# 'texture' function call on sampler2D in glsl makes entire screen gray

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I am trying to use both `samplerBuffer` and `sampler2D` in fragment shader.

With `samplerBuffer` alone it works fine and code looks like this

```
#version 460
out vec4 FragColor;
in vec2 texcoord;

uniform sampler2D background;
uniform samplerBuffer OctreeData;

...

void main()
{    
    Ray ray = initRay();
    /*this function does raytraycing in octree and retrieves data
    from samplerBuffer using texelFetch function.*/
    Contact res = iterativeHitNodes(ray);

    if(res.hit)
      FragColor = assignNodeColor(res); //sets color of the node
    else
      FragColor = getBackground(origin, ray);
}
```

Then if I add `FragColor = texture(background, texcoord.xy); return;` line at the beginning of `main` function, it successfully reads the image and displays it. **(A)**

But when `texture` is called in `getBackground` it shows gray screen. And turns out shader is not working at all — When I intentionally load heavy models framerate stays the same. But there are no shader compile errors.

And the biggest "what" is that screen remains gray even when `texture` is never called **(B)**. For example when `backgroundType` is always 0 and  `getBackground` function is:

```
vec3 getBackground(vec3 from, vec3 direction)
{
    if(backgroundType == 0)
        return getSkyBackground(from, direction);
    else if(backgroundType == 1)
    {
        return texture(background, texcoord.xy).xyz;
    }

    return vec3(0);
}
```

Seems like a sheer presence of `texture` call discards fragments.

- this is how it looks in **A** case https://i.stack.imgur.com/XplAP.jpg
- in case of **B** https://i.stack.imgur.com/bj8gP.jpg
- this is how it should look and how it looks on CPU https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3yMB.jpg

**P.S.** In Debug it works as intended. For some reason, the problem appears in Release mode

**P.P.S** Most of the shader's code https://pastebin.com/SWCQ9HUw

Answer (score 2):

See [OpenGL Shading Language 4.60 Specification (HTML) - Texture Functions](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.html#texture-functions):

> Some texture functions (non-“Lod” and non-“Grad” versions) may require implicit derivatives. Implicit derivatives are undefined within non-uniform control flow and for non-fragment shader texture fetches.

If you are using a texture and [`texture`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/texture.xhtml) for texture lookup make sure that all invocations in the invocation group execute the same control-flow path:

```c
vec3 getBackground(vec3 from, vec3 direction, vec3 backgroundColor)
{
    if (backgroundType == 0)
        return getSkyBackground(from, direction);
    else if (backgroundType == 1)
        return backgroundColor;

    return vec3(0);
}
```

```c
void main()
{
    vec3 backgroundColor = texture(background, texcoord.xy).xyz;
    
    Ray ray = initRay();
    /*this function does raytraycing in octree and retrieves data
    from samplerBuffer using texelFetch function.*/
    Contact res = iterativeHitNodes(ray);

    if(res.hit)
      FragColor = assignNodeColor(res); //sets color of the node
    else
      FragColor = getBackground(origin, ray, backgroundColor);
}
```

Comment: So that means we shouldn't use calls to `texture` in branched conditions? But if all branches have a call to it (with potentially different arguments) it's fine?

Comment: @Beko *" if all branches have a call to it (with potentially different arguments) it's fine?"*  - No it's not. Compute the texture coordinates in branches, but do the lookup in uniform control flow.

Comment: @Rabbid76 This time it turns out that shader halts after `iterativeHitNodes` (where `texelFetch` is called) being called. If I remove it `texture` seems to work fine even with branching